# 'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component' ERROR when accessing the context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the following error when I access the context api from my componentDidMount method. It is caused by refreshing the page, then the application crashes. If I'm navigating it normally I do not get an error.

```
react-dom.development.js?4646:506 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Details (created by WithStyles(Details))
    in WithStyles(Details) (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by Apis)
    in Switch (created by Apis)
    in Apis (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by ProtectedApp)
    in Switch (created by ProtectedApp)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by WithStyles(Layout))
    in WithStyles(Layout) (created by ProtectedApp)
    in MuiThemeProviderOld (created by ProtectedApp)
    in IntlProvider (created by ProtectedApp)
    in ProtectedApp (created by LoadableComponent)
    in LoadableComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by Store)
    in Switch (created by Store)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by Store)
    in Store
    in MuiThemeProviderOld
```

I found that it is caused [by this line](https://github.com/dushansilva/carbon-apimgt/blob/04adaf38d05066a8e601c836083eee6e97769306/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.store.feature/src/main/resources/store-new/source/src/app/components/Apis/Details/Credentials/Credentials.jsx#L173) where I access the object returned from the context.

Any input on why this is happening and how can I fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try updating `components/Apis/Details/index.js:294` to `this.state.active = currentLink[0]` and see if it works?

Comment: It will work... but we should not update state like this.

Comment: @Piyush Just wanted to confirm my theory, I shared my thoughts in the answer.

Comment: You are updating state in a component that is no longer live. Watch for `setTimeout` or `setIntervals` if you are not clearing them or really anything that could update your state when you change view to new component, but is still running code in another one.

Comment: @jank I tried wrapping the content in the did mount with a settimeout, the isssue stopped happening but however i did not get any of the props that I should have received from the context

Comment: Can you share your code that is providing the issue?

Comment: @jank code i pointed in that link. When i access the context api from the componentDidMount method. [this](https://github.com/dushansilva/carbon-apimgt/blob/04adaf38d05066a8e601c836083eee6e97769306/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.store.feature/src/main/resources/store-new/source/src/app/components/Apis/Details/Credentials/Credentials.jsx#L173)

Comment: @dushansilva how sure are you the error happen on this line of code, i'd say error is caused by `components/Apis/Details/index.js`. Try removing all `updateActiveLink()` and instead have a lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` and use `nextProps` instead of `this.props`. it's really hard to tell where error occurs, i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to have been bubbling up from the [Details/index.js:294](https://github.com/dushansilva/carbon-apimgt/blob/04adaf38d05066a8e601c836083eee6e97769306/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.store.feature/src/main/resources/store-new/source/src/app/components/Apis/Details/index.jsx#L294) because the method `updateActiveLink` is invoked in render method.

I guess when you reload the page, this condition kicks in and tries to `setState` when the component is still rendering which is not the reason `setState` is designed for. `setState` will invoked `render` again unless the `shouldComponentUpdate` hook returns false which it does not in your case.

So, you can choose to change the way you handle setting the `active` link either in componentWillMount by setting it to a variable or by invoking it in `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` lifecycle hooks.

Another solution would be to return the calculated `active` state and use it accordingly

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({active: this.getActiveLink()});
  ...
}

getActiveLink() {
    const { active } = this.state;
    const currentLink = this.props.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+(?=\/$|$)/g);

    if (currentLink && currentLink.length > 0 && active !== currentLink[0]) {
        return currentLink[0];
    }

    return active;
}

render() {
  const active = this.getActiveLink();
  ...
}
```

Or a little more controversial fix would be to mutate in the method like below. IMHO state variable is just another, instance variable nothing fancy about it, as long as you are passing down the render cycle mutating state responsibly should not cause any side effects. Since it's almost as if you are doing operations on the state in the render method that too on a string variable `active`, it should not be a blatant error.

```
componentDidMount() {
  updateActiveLink(true);
  ...
}

updateActiveLink(setState) {
    const { active } = this.state;
    const currentLink = this.props.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+(?=\/$|$)/g);

    if (currentLink && currentLink.length > 0 && active !== currentLink[0]) {
      if(setState) 
        this.setState({ active: currentLink[0] });
      else
        this.state.active = currentLink[0];
    }
}

render() {
  this.updateActiveLink(false);
  ...
}
```

**NOTE:** I am not encouraging state mutation or anything, I see it differently and use it differently as long as the render cycle obeys it's rules. Again this is one of my observations using `setState` in quite many complex components.

**PS:** Have not tried running the code, just a hunch / observation. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hey thanks for your detailed reply! I tried your theory out by commenting out all the places updateActiveLink method is called, but the issue still exists. One thing to note is that this started happening when i accessed the context api [here](https://github.com/dushansilva/carbon-apimgt/blob/04adaf38d05066a8e601c836083eee6e97769306/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.store.feature/src/main/resources/store-new/source/src/app/components/Apis/Details/Credentials/Credentials.jsx#L173)

Comment: So, the stack trace is the same even after commenting out the updateActivationLink method usage?